# Printing to console in x86 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, console, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am unable to print text other than pre defined variables into the console. For example,

```
add dx, 48
mov rax, 1 
movzx rsi, dx
mov rdx, 1
syscall
```

somehow results in a "Floating point exception (core dumped)". Dx should be an integer from 0 to 9, and from what I understand which could very well be wrong adding 48 should make it the ascii form of 0 to 9 since 48 is the ascii value for '0'. Please help.

I tried narrowing down what went wrong by instead doing

```
mov rax, 1
mov rsi, 'test'
mov rdx, 4
syscall
```

which should've just printed "test", but instead it prints nothing which I have no clue why

Comment: `write(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)` takes a *pointer* to the data, not by value, so you're just passing invalid pointers to write, which will return `-EFAULT`.  In your first example, none of the the instructions you show will raise a SIGFPE, including `syscall`.  Perhaps that was part of a loop that used `div` to get digits, and the bug was in how you used `div`, causing an arithmetic exception (#DE) leading to SIGFPE.  Run you code under GDB to see which instruction faulted.